# How to correctly import yahoofinance into python?

Tags: python

I am trying to import yahoo finance into jupyter notebook and get price data but I keep getting the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'yfinance' has no attribute 'get_historical_price_data'
```

Maybe I imported the module incorrectly:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install yahoofinancials
import yfinance as yf
```

Here is the problematic code:

```
data=yf.get_historical_price_data(start=start_date,end=end_date)
```

Comment: I tried that too, no success but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

According to the usage examples on the PyPI page for [`yahoofinancials`](https://pypi.org/project/yahoofinancials/), you need to create an instance of the `YahooFinancials` object first, then access the methods through it:

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

ticker = "AAPL"
aapl = YahooFinancials(ticker)

data = aapl.get_historical_price_data('2008-09-15', '2018-09-15', 'weekly')
```